# Moodle HTML Quickform select options not loading correctly

Tags: php, html, pear, moodle, quickform

I have 2 select lists

> 1. ausers - List all available users
> 2. susers - Displays selected users

I use moodles `global $SESSION` variable to store the users selection items
and then I load the selected items into the susers list using the `$SESSION->susers`
variable.
This happens when the user clicks on the **"Add user"** button.

I am using a session variable to save the selections since I need to post
the form more than once. (The form will have another **course** selection list)

I cannot use javascript to accomplish this since my client wants the script to function without js support.

**NOTE :**

> My code loads the options correctly
>   but displays the current `$SESSION` data
>   and the previous `$SESSION` data in the
>   select list.I think the problem might be a refresh issue of the select element.
>   I use the following statement to load the selected users in the susers element
>   `$susers_el->load($susers);`

**To better illustrate the problem :**

On "Add user" button click

> **Selected users (ausers)**
>   1.Joe
>   2.James
>   **Select List (susers)**
>   1.Joe
>   2.James

When I want to add another user to the susers list the following happens:
On "Add user" button click

> **Selected users (ausers)**
>   3.Lance
>   **Select List (susers)**
>   1.Joe
>   2.James
>   1.Joe
>   2.James
>   3.Lance

Below is the current code, any help or advice is most appreciated.

```
class learner_progress_form extends moodleform {
  function definition() {
    global $SESSION, $CFG;
    fb('Create form');
    $mform  = & $this->_form;
    //User Section
    $mform->addElement('header', 'site_users', 'Site Users');
    $objs[]    = array();
    $ausers[]  = array();
    //All users & courses sessions
    $SESSION->all_users   = $this->get_all_users(); 
    //Available users $ courses
    $ausers   = $SESSION->all_users; 
    //Form design
    $objs[0] =& $mform->createElement('select', 'ausers', 'Available users', $ausers, 'size="15"');
    $objs[0]->setMultiple(true);
    $objs[1] =& $mform->createElement('select', 'susers', 'Selected users', null, 'size="15"');
    $objs[1]->setMultiple(true);
    $grp =& $mform->addElement('group', 'usersgrp', 'Users', $objs, ' ', false);

    $objs = array();
    $objs[] =& $mform->createElement('submit', 'uaddsel','Add');
    $objs[] =& $mform->createElement('submit', 'uremovesel', 'Remove');
    $grp =& $mform->addElement('group', 'ubuttonsgrp', null, $objs, array(' ', '<br />'), false);
    $renderer =& $mform->defaultRenderer();
    $template = '<label class="qflabel" style="vertical-align:top">{label}</label> {element}';
    $renderer->setGroupElementTemplate($template, 'usersgrp');

    //Button Section
    $mform->addElement('header','actions','Generate report');
    $objs = array();
    $objs[] =& $mform->createElement('submit', 'submit', 'Go');
    $mform->addElement('group', 'actionsgrp', 'Generate report with selected data', $objs, ' ', false);
  }

  function definition_after_data() {
    global $SESSION;
    fb('definition after data');
    $mform      =& $this->_form; 
    //Get users group and elements
    $usersgrp   =& $mform->getElement('usersgrp')->getElements();
    //Selected Users
    $susers_el  =& $usersgrp[1]; //selected users 
    $susers     = $SESSION->susers;
    $susers_el->load($susers); 
  }

function get_all_users() {
    global $SESSION, $CFG;
    $ausers = array();
    $userlist = get_records_sql(
      "select id, firstname, lastname, email 
      from {$CFG->prefix}user
      where id NOT IN (0,1,2)"); //exclude empty,admin & guest
    foreach($userlist as $user){
      if (!empty($user) ) {
        $ausers[$user->id] = $user->firstname." ".$user->lastname;
      }
    }
    //sort($ausers);
    return $ausers;
  }

/**
 * Add user(s) selections to list
 * $SESSION->s_users : Stores previous selections
 * TBD   : Seems to be a refresh bug
 * TOFIX : Duplication - possible refresh bug 
 **/
  function set_user_selections() {
    global $SESSION, $CFG;
    $usergrp        =& $this->_form->getElement('usersgrp')->getElements();
    $ausers_el      =& $usergrp[0];
    $susers_el      =& $usergrp[1];
    $susers         = $ausers_el->getSelected();
    $ausers         = $SESSION->all_users;
    $users          = array();
    //build selected users array
    foreach ($susers as $user=>$id) {
      $users[$id] = $ausers[$id];
    }
    //Check selected user sessions
    if (isset($SESSION->susers) )
    {
      //Remove duplicate selections
      foreach ($SESSION->susers as $id=>$val) {
        if (in_array($id, $users) )
        {
          unset($SESSION->susers[$id]);
        }
      }
      $users = $SESSION->susers + $users;
    }
    $SESSION->susers = $users;
    //asort($users);
    fb('User being loaded in select list');
    fb($users);
    $susers_el->load($users);
  }
```

Comment: What does `get_all_users` do? Code?

Comment: Hi, I have added the get_all_users function to above code sample.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any reason for your problem. It would be nice if you could reproduce the issue on a script that can be run standalone. I could run it then, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
I basically had to check the $_POST variables to perform the appropriate action on my select lists.
This had to be done in the `definition_after_data` function every time
the form is loaded (refreshed, posted etc). The session variables work great to keep load the users previous selections.

These simple lines of code solved my problem.

```
//Load users  
if (!isset($_POST['uaddsel']) and !isset($_POST['uremovesel']) ) { 
  $this->load_session_users(); //load previous selected user in susers 
} 
//Load courses 
if (!isset($_POST['caddsel']) and !isset($_POST['cremovesel']) ) { 
  $this->load_session_courses(); 
}
```

and in my index.php i would call :

```
//Add user
  if (isset($_POST['uaddsel']) ) {
    //add user
    $form->set_user_selections();
  }
  //remove user
  if (isset($_POST['uremovesel']) ) {
    $form->remove_selected_users();
  }
```